# Redirect old Wordpress permalinks site from subdirectory on one domain to root of another domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm aware of lots of other questions re htaccess redirects, but can't find anything that seems to work in my specific scenario.

I have a wordpress site installed at `www.oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir`.  This site is using permalinks, so has the following in the `/wp-subdir/.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp-subdir/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp-subdir/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

On the settings page, both "WordPress address (URL)" and "Site address (URL)" are set to `http://www.oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir` - That is, the site was NOT being presented as though it existed in the root - an option explained on the [Giving wordpress its own directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)
 codex page)

I have copied this site to `www.newsite.com.au/wp-subdir`, but here it *is* set up per the codex mentioned above.  That is, in the settings page for this domain, "WordPress address (URL)" is set to `http://www.newsite.com.au/wp-subdir` and "Site address (URL)" is set to `http://www.newsite.com.au`.

Both sites are working fine in isolation.

However, now I want any hits on the old site to be re-directed to the analogous location on the new site.

**Examples of what I'd like**

`http://www.oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir` -> `http://www.newsite.com.au`

`http://www.oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir/products` -> `http://www.newsite.com.au/products`

`http://www.oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir/images/imagePermaLink` -> `http://www.newsite.com.au/images/imagePermaLink`

`http://www.oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir/?s=search+terms` -> `http://www.newsite.com.au/?s=search+terms` (displays search results page)

`http://www.oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir/unknown-page` -> `http://www.newsite.com.au/unknown-page` (displays 404 page)

Link from google image results -> `http://www.newsite.com.au/images/imagePermaLink`

**What I've tried**

1. Adding a .htaccess file to the root of `www.oldsite.com.au`, with
   `Redirect 301 /wp-subdir http://www.newsite.com.au/`
2. Using this in the root .htaccess file instead:

   `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)+oldsite\.com\.au  [NC]
   RewriteRule ^wp-subdir/(.*)  http://www.newsite.com.au/ [R=301,NC,L]`
3. Changing the re-write rule on `oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir/.htaccess` (listed in full earlier) from:
   `RewriteRule . /wp-subdir/index.php [R=301,L]`

to: 
`RewriteRule . www.newsite.com.au/index.php [R=301,L]`

All changes (in isolation) result in the following situations:

`http://www.oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir` -> `http://www.newsite.com.au` **PASS**

`http://www.oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir/products` -> `http://www.newsite.com.au` **FAIL**

`http://www.oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir/images/imagePermaLink` -> page not found error (not the site's 404 template) **FAIL**

`http://www.oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir/?s=search+terms` -> `http://www.oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir/?s=search+terms` **FAIL**

`http://www.oldsite.com.au/wp-subdir/unknown-page` -> `http://www.newsite.com.au`  **FAIL**

Link from google image results -> `http://www.newsite.com.auimages/imagePermaLink` (missing slash after domain name) **FAIL**

If it's not already obvious I have little understanding of .htaccess files.... so any help appreciated!

### EDIT:

On looking at this again this morning using my iPad, it turns out that my option 1 above is working after all.  And now again on my laptop it's (almost*) working fine too.  Perhaps some browser caching on my laptop was causing previous re-direct attempts to be remembered.

*In Chrome, some pages display OK after the redirect but the page-loading spinning wheel icon on the tab never finishes (and using the developer tools the network and timeline tabs have no data).

*In Chrome, the redirect from the google images search still has a missing slash after the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Redirect 301 /wp-subdir/ http://www.newsite.com.au/
```

Note the addition of the / at the end of the first string.

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much for the suggestion.  I haven't tried it yet though; I've added an edit to my question to show that what I had already tried is (now?) almost working.  In light of that new info, do you think your suggestion is still worth trying?  I'm hesitant to 'trial-and-error' test this because of the apparent timing/caching issues, unless you're still confident that your suggestion will help?

Comment: Well, I've used it successfully. I originally found it many years ago when I was first starting to use Redirect and looking at docs. For example, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/remapping.html, third example down: "Resource moved to another server".

Comment: Champion, thanks mate. I'll give it a go then.  Thanks for the authoritative source too - adding to my bookmarks ;-)  I really appreciate your help.